# How to reopen the form designer in Visual Studio 2019 while the `MyForm.cs` is missing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I Created a windows form by using an empty `C++` `CLR` project and got an error in a new tab of `form designer` and I closed that tab and fixed the error in `MyForm.cpp` by copying the following code:

```
#include "MyForm.h"
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThreadAttribute]
void Main(array<String^>^ args) {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    //MFP10 is your project name
    MFP10::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

and now I am trying to access that designer form tab by double clicking the `MyForm.h` , suddenly it is showing me the code instead of opening the form in the designer.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the Issue. If you have this Issue you can follow the steps to solve it.
According to the version I am using is `VS Enterprise 2019 Registered`

**Steps:**

Options>>Environment>>Preview Features >> and
`Enable the Preview of .net Core SDK`

Restart the app and open the project and double click on the `MyForm.h` under header directory.

[image: Solution Screen Shot]